# Combine Easy Auth and ASP.NET Middelware

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-web-app-service

We have a range of API’s that is hosted in Azure App Services and protected by ASP.NET Core Middleware.

When navigating to the URL, we list the endpoints using Swagger. And if you have a valid token, you can invoke the endpoints.

We want to protect the entire URL, so only users in our Azure AD can access the site and see the endpoints.

I was thinking that we can achieve this by setting Easy Auth **to Log in with azure Active Directory**.

1: Will this setting have any effect on the Middleware?
Or will it just act as “first layer” of protection and only forward the request if authenticated by Azure AD first?

2: Is there another (better) way to solve this scenario?

(I guess we also need to set allowedAudiences/domain_hint to our own AD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be (1), act as a first layer and only forward the request if the user has been authenticated by the whichever mechanism you configured in the Authentication/Authorization blade of your App Service.

As to your second question, it really depends on what granularity you'll need. If every API call needs to be authorized, then I don't see any issue with using Easy Auth. However, is there reason, since you've configured your middleware, why using `[Authorize]` isn't no longer sufficient?

Comment: [Authorize] is indeed sufficient from an Auth point of view.. But we like to enable swagger on all our API's including Production API's. Any outside user could potential navigate to the API and see the endpoints and request json. Since all the API's are only consumed by users/app from our own Azure AD (or own on-premise), there is really no need to allow outside users to see the endpoints.

Comment: I guess we could just disable swagger when deployed to azure. But swagger just makes is very easy to test the endpoints.

Comment: You could still enable swagger on your endpoints but only clients with a valid token would be able test it, otherwise the user would get a 404. If you wanted to hide swagger from anyone not registered within your tenant, then Easy Auth would be the way to go because a user would be forced to login before even getting to swagger.